# gerrit "ready to submit" but no submit button is displayed after change submit rule

Tags: gerrit

I want to apply four eyes principle on gerrit. After reading the doc I found the example is already there. [see the example](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_13_1_1_2_code_review). I just changed the example prolog a little bit: make the change submittable if the total score is 3 or higher, and remove the "verified" label.

After apply the new submit rule, new commits correctly get the "Ready to Submit" status after gets code-review score 3 or higher. however, the "submit" button is not displayed, even with the administrator account.

I am sure I have the "submit" permission set properly to that branch: If I remove the rules.pl file, the submit button is displayed.

In fact, I've tested all examples in the official doc. All has the same problem (Except for the [Nothing is submittable Example](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_3_nothing_is_submittable) because nothing is submittalbe, and the [Reusing the default submit policy example](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_reusing_the_default_submit_policy) because no rule is changed). What is the purpose of a "Ready to Submit" status without a submit button? I must be missing something.

I found little clue about writing gerrit submit rule prolog except for the official documents, which I've read intensively. Quite frustrated now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tested some and looks like not all are working out of the box: Example 1: Make every change submittable is working for me. Example 8: Make change submittable only if Code-Review+2 is given by a non author version with default_submit does not work but version without default_submit works. I used gerrit 2.13.6

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I forget to say my gerrit version. I am using gerrit 2.12.3 .

Comment: @Philip The two example you mentioned did not work for me. And I also tried to remove the "default_submit", did not work either.

Comment: To be honest i never used prolog before you can try asking also here where all the Gerrit Guru's are https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/repo-discuss. I'm planning to do some more tests when i have free time. Maybe these examples are not compatible with your Gerrit version or in 2.12.3 rules are disabled by default try [rules]
        enable = true in etc/gerrit.config